How can I change contents of DataTable with setState
I have a problem. I am beginner for Flutter. I am making a share app and when I add a new share, it doesn't appear on DataTable. Here is my main page and share adding page code;
MainPage

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Share> shares = [
    Share(ShareCode, ShareQuantity, AverageCost)
  ];
  var dbhelper = DBHelper();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My Portfolio'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        body: buildBody(context),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        floatingActionButton: buttons(context));
  }

  Widget tableHead(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
        columns: [
          DataColumn(label: Text("Symbol")),
        ],
        rows: shares
            .map<DataRow>(
                (item) => DataRow(cells: [DataCell(Text(item.shareCode))]))
            .toList());
  }

  Widget scrollTableHead(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child:
        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
          DataTable(
              columns: [
                DataColumn(label: Text("Price")),
                DataColumn(label: Text("%")),
                DataColumn(label: Text("Quantity")),
                DataColumn(label: Text("Cost")),
                DataColumn(label: Text("P/L"))
              ],
              rows: shares
                  .map<DataRow>((element) => DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Text('Price')),
                DataCell(Text("diff")),
                DataCell(Text(element.shareQuantity.toString())),
                DataCell(Text(element.averageCost.toString())),
                DataCell(Text("P/L"))
              ]))
                  .toList())
        ]));
  }

  Widget tableBody(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Row(children: [
          Expanded(child: symbolList()),
        ]));
  }

  Widget symbolList() {
    return Column(
        children: shares.map((e) {
          return Row(
            children: [Text(e.shareCode)],
          );
        }).toList());
  }

  Widget buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(children: [
              tableHead(context),
              Expanded(child: scrollTableHead(context))
            ]),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget buttons(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          fit: FlexFit.tight,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ShareAdd(shares)));
            },
            child: Row(
              children: [Icon(Icons.add), Text("Yeni Hisse")],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

Share Add Page:

class ShareAdd extends StatefulWidget {
  late List<Share> shares;

  ShareAdd(List<Share> shares) {
    this.shares = shares;
  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ShareAddState(shares);
  }
}

class ShareAddState extends State<ShareAdd> with ShareValidationMaxin {
  late Share share;
  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late List<Share> shares;
  var dbhelper = DBHelper();
  late Provider shareModel;

  ShareAddState(List<Share> shares) {
    this.shares = shares;
    share = Share.withoutInfo();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add New Share"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              buildShareNameField(),
              buildShareQuantitiyField(),
              buildShareCostField(),
              buildSubmitButton(context)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildShareNameField() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration:
          InputDecoration(labelText: "Share Code", hintText: "Ex. NVDA"),
      validator: validateShareName,
      onSaved: (String? name) {
        if (name != null) {
          share.shareCode = name;
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildShareQuantitiyField() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration:
          InputDecoration(labelText: "Share Quantity", hintText: "Ex. 10"),
      validator: validateQuantity,
      onSaved: (String? quantity) {
        if (quantity != null) {
          share.shareQuantity = double.parse(quantity);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildShareCostField() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration:
          InputDecoration(labelText: "Share Cost", hintText: "Ex. 100"),
      validator: validateCost,
      onSaved: (String? cost) {
        if (cost != null) {
          share.averageCost = double.parse(cost);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildSubmitButton(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            formKey.currentState!.save();
            setState(() {
              shares.add(share);
            });
            //dbhelper.insert(share);
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }
        },
        child: Text("SAVE"));
  }

}


I tried Provider class and I can't change DataTable. On my another app, setState() worked, I can't understand why it doesn't work now?
